# How to send a ref to a function as a parameter in React Native?

Tags: javascript, react-native, ref

I've imported a custom `component` into my `screen` and rendered it in the `render()` function. Then, created a `ref` to that custom component. Now, the `render()` function simply looks like this.

```
render() {
  return (
    <View>
      <MyComponent ref={component => this.myComponent = component} />
    </View>
  )
}
```

Then, I've created another function to access the state of my custom component. I wrote it like this.

```
myFunction = (ref) => {
  ref.setState({ myState: myValue })
}
```

Then, I called that function like this.

```
this.myFunction(this.myComponent)
```

But, it does not work. It gives me the following error.

`null is not an object (evaluating 'ref.setState')`

Actually what I need this `myFunction` to do is,

```
this.myComponent.setState({ myState: myValue })
```

Can you please help me to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

ref is not your this object. it's dom for your componnet. For setState you need this of your component.

you can pass this as argument.

`myFunction(this)`

Now you will be able to do ref.setState in myFunction.

```
function myFunction(ref) {
    ref.setState({ myState: myValue })
}
```

Comment: Can you explain more further? If write the function like that, how should I call it?

Comment: Really appreciate if you can help me to solve this problem.

Comment: you can simply call myFunction(this) from anywhere in your component. you can keep function anywhere outside of your component.

Comment: The problem is this. I have rendered the component 4 times and I have given them 4 different `ref` s. So, I want to call those function for each component separately only for the component which I need.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56323864/how-to-access-ref-of-a-component-through-a-function-in-react-native

Answer (score 0):

To use `setState`, just use your component's context (`this` keyword). The context also have your ref in it, so you don't need to pass it as an argument if you are inside one component(not forwarding down to children)

```
myFunction = (event) => {
 this.myComponent  // -> points to your ref, DOM element
 this.setState() // use your setState like that
}
```

Don't forget to bind your context in parent component if you want to pass the handler to the child components. Refer to this [useful topic](https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html)

EDIT: Based on your comment, I guess you want to update the parent state by calling a handler in some other component. To do that, you need to create a handler in your parent component, bind the context and pass it as a property to the child component. Next up, you need to assign this handler in your child component. You cannot pass a context with `setState` method via argument or ref, this is just not how it works in javascript and in react.

Example:

```
// ParentComponent.js
class ParentComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      value: 1,
    };
    this.onChangeHandler = this.onChangeHandler.bind(this);
  }

  onChangeHandler(event) {
    this.setState({
      value: someNewValue // will update state on parent component
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <SomeComponent>{this.state.value}</SomeComponent>
        <ChildrenComponent onChangeHandler={this.onChangeHandler} />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

// ChildrenComponent.js
const ChildrenComponent = (props) => (
  <View>
    <Button
      onPress={props.onChangeHandler}
      title="click me to change parent state"
    />
  </View>
);
```

Hopefully, this is what you need :)

Comment: Can you please edit your answer as a complete answer? I mean, the complete function and I need to know how should I call the function.

Comment: It depends on what you want to do with that function. Could you please explain your specific case?

Comment: It's right I can do it without any function. But, I want to know how to do it through the function. Can you please see what I need in my question? Really appreciate if you can help me to solve this.

Comment: I have edited the answer, please ask if you have any further questions