# How to access ref of a component through a function in React Native?

Tags: javascript, react-native, ref

I've imported a custom `component` into my `screen` and rendered it in the `render()` function. Then, created a `ref` to that custom component. Now, the `render()` function simply looks like this.

```
render() {
  return (
    <View>
      <MyComponent ref={component => this.myComponent1 = component} />
      <MyComponent ref={component => this.myComponent2 = component} />
      <MyComponent ref={component => this.myComponent3 = component} />
    </View>
  )
}
```

Then, In the same `screen` file, I've created another function to access the state of my custom component. I wrote it like this.

```
myFunction = (ref) => {
  ref.setState({ myState: myValue })
}
```

Then, I want to call that function for those separate components separately like this. (In the `screen` file)

```
this.myFunction(this.myComponent1)
this.myFunction(this.myComponent2)
this.myFunction(this.myComponent3)
```

But, it does not work. It gives me the following error.

`null is not an object (evaluating 'ref.setState')`

Actually what I need this `myFunction` to do is,

```
this.myComponent1.setState({ myState: myValue })
this.myComponent2.setState({ myState: myValue })
this.myComponent3.setState({ myState: myValue })
```

The state `myState` is in the `component` while I want to access it through the `myFunction()` in my `screen` file.

Can you please help me to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

This is not good practice to setState of child component from parent component.
I am assuming you want to set some value to your child component's state by trying this approach.

You can keep these values in your local state and pass it to props and your child component will re-render / get updated value there.

```
class Component {
  constructor() {
    this.state = {
      myValues: {
        component1: "abc",
        component2: "xyz",
        component3: "123",
      }
    }
  }

  myFunction(componentName, newValue) {
    this.setState({
      myValues: {
        ...this.state.myValues,
        [componentName]: newValue
      }
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <MyComponent value={this.state.myValues.component1} />
        <MyComponent value={this.state.myValues.component2} />
        <MyComponent value={this.state.myValues.component3} />
      </View>
    )
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

First make sur that MyComponent is a component and not a stateless Component, then, to change states, try this :

```
myFunction = (ref) => {
  ref.current.setState({ myState: myValue }
}
```

and of course , for it to work, your component need to be already mounts, If you try for example to call this in the constructor, it will not work

Comment: Sorry, did not work. Can you please suggest me another solution?

Comment: I tested it, and it worked for me, I just created the ref not with same approach, I used React.createRef()

Answer (score 0):

Inside your component,  in the componentDidMount function please add

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.props.refs(this) 
}

setState(key, value){
    this.setState({[key]:value})
}
```

and please change the ref param to refs

```
<MyComponent refs={component => this.myComponent1 = component} />

myFunction = (ref) => {
    ref.setState('myState', 'myValue')
}
```

Comment: Sorry, did not work. Can you please suggest me another solution?